# What can we conclude about $P(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n\le na)$?

Tags: probability, analysis

If for a sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$, we know
$$P(X_i\le a)\le e^{-ca}, \quad i=1,2,3,\dots, n$$

What can we conclude about $P(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n\le na)$?

Can we get
$$P(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n\le na)=P(X_i\le a, \mbox{ for any $i=1,2,\dots,n$})=(e^{-ca})^n$$
if we know that $X_i$ is independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n \leq na) \leq P(\bigcup_i (X_i \leq a)) \leq ne^{-ca}$ even without independence.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. I think the event that $X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n\le na$ means  that events $X_1\le a$, $X_2\le a$, .., $X_n\le a$ all occur. Is it inspection of all $\{X_i\le a\}$? Why this is the union of all events?

Comment: @Hermi If you know that $X_i$'s are non-negative r.v.'s then you can say $X_i \leq a$ for all $i$. Otherwise you can only say that $X_I \leq a$ for some $i$.

Comment: Can you explain the first inequality in more detail? Thanks.

Comment: @Hermi You prove it by contradiction: If $X_i >a$ for all $i$ then $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n >a+a+\cdots+a=na$.